# How to migrate from Pages Router to Next.js App Router?

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js13

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect } from "react";

import { useAppDispatch } from "lib/store/hooks";
import { ModalName, setModalState } from "lib/store/modal/modalSlice";

type QueryParams = {
  modal?: ModalName;
};

const ModalWrapper: React.FC = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const { modal, ...rest } = router.query as QueryParams;

    if (!modal) return;

    dispatch(setModalState({ modal, state: { open: true, payload: { item: rest } } }));
  }, [router.query, dispatch]);
```

I want to change the router from Pages Router to App Router, but I have some difficulties.
I tried to do in this way:
I changed the import in next/navigation, but after that I'm stuck . I guess i need to use useSearchParams(). Any advice?

```
 import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useEffect } from "react";

import { useAppDispatch } from "lib/store/hooks";
import { ModalName, setModalState } from "lib/store/modal/modalSlice";

type QueryParams = {
  modal?: ModalName;
};

const ModalWrapper: React.FC = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    const { modal, ...rest } = router.query as QueryParams;

    if (!modal) return;

    dispatch(setModalState({ modal, state: { open: true, payload: { item: rest } } }));
  }, [router.query, dispatch]);
```

Comment: Router from `next/navigation` is being used only for navigation change (push, back, forward, etc). To use router params in app, you need to use hook `const searchParams = useSearchParams();` `searchParams.get('page')`